# How to increase length of Assumed Role token or refresh session when using FargateCluster, Dask Cloud Provider

Tags: dask

Im running dask locally and spinning up fargate cluster in AWS.

Its assuming a role correctly and starting up the cluster.

After six hours its permissions fail, I have set the maximum session duration on the role to 12 hours but it seems to be getting a defailt 6 hour token anyway and not asking for a 12 hour token.

Is there a way to tell it to get a token for the max session duration of 12 hours or do I need to refresh the token somewhow?

feels like I need to set duration_seconds somewhere to get a full 12 hour token....

cluster setup like:

```py
cluster = FargateCluster(
        cloudwatch_logs_group="{project}_log_group",
        cluster_name_template="{project}-{uuid}",
        environment={"DEFAULT_GSF_VERSION": gsf_version},
        image=f"{aws_account_id}.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/{project}:latest",
        n_workers=9,
        scheduler_cpu=4096,
        scheduler_mem=30720,
        scheduler_timeout="240 minutes",
        security_groups=[aws_security_group_id],
        task_role_arn=f"arn:aws:iam::{aws_account_id}:role/{project}ECSTaskRole",
        worker_cpu=4096,
        worker_mem=30720,
        worker_extra_args=algorithm_extra_cluster_args,
        fargate_use_private_ip=use_private_ip,
        vpc=vpc,
        subnets=subnets,
        skip_cleanup=True,
        platform_version="LATEST",
        shutdown_on_close=True,
        mount_points=mount_points,
        volumes=volumes,
    )
    cluster.adapt(minimum=9, maximum=80)
    logger.info(f"dashboard_link is: {cluster.dashboard_link}")
```

I have set the maximum session duration on my role to 12 hours, seems it still only gets a 6 hour token.

I tried adding seconds_duration=42300 to AWS config files hoping to override the default 6 hour token, still lost perms after 6 hours

Comment: You may want to reference this question as an issue at dask-cloudprovider

Comment: thanks I couldnt find a dask-cloudprovider tag, I  will add it to the title. edit- aaah an issue, I see will do

Comment: hmmm the only option for an issue is a bug report, Im not sure if it is a bug

Comment: It may be a bug or it may be a feature request ;)